# JqPlot Bar and Line Chart combine

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqplot

I have situation where i have to combine bar and line chart I have the below data please check if have any solution of this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var s1 = [ 59, 175, 148, 213, 19, 213, 144, 64, 229, 89, 59, 363, 5, 71, 31];//bar chart
var s2 = [66, 220, 87, 59, 15, 227, 134, 46, 139, 30, 18, 71, 2, 17, 2];
//bar chart
var line1= [98.81, 98.90, 99.00, 99.17, 99.35, 99.36, 99.46, 99.56, 99.71, 99.82, 99.87, 99.89, 99.92, 99.95,99.98];//data for line chart
var line2 = [ 99.52, 99.52, 99.52, 99.52, 99.52,99.52,99.52,99.52, 99.52, 99.52, 99.52, 99.52, 99.52, 99.52];//data for line chart


var ticks = ['Rakhine', 'Ayeyarwady', 'Magway', 'Bago', 'Kayah', 'Sagaing', 'Shan', 'Kachin', 'Yangon', 'Mon', 'Kayin', 'Mandalay',
    'Chin', 'Tanintharyi', 'Naypyitaw' ];
//now i need to combine bar and line with the same plot
plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', [s1, s2], {
 seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,show: true,
        pointLabels: { show: true }
    },

    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: ticks
        }
    }
});
});
```

Description:

[image]